# Indentation of ol with multiple lines and custom counter

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have an ordered list with a custom counter, multiple lines in the list items and a list item background, like this:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  background: orange;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </li>
  <li>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </li>
</ol>
```

Now the counter is inside the list item. I want the counter to be left to the list item, i.e. left to the first line and the following lines start where the first line started.

I already read a thread in which the answer is to use `display: table-row` for the `li`'s and `display: table-cell` for the `li::before` but that doesn't work with my background:

[image]

How can I fix this to show the counter next to the whole li element?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `li` to `display: flex` and align the counter to the top.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  background: orange;
  padding: 8px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  align-self: start;
 margin-right:8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </li>
  <li>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works in the minimal example. But this does align the elements in the ```li``` like flex. I have some ```span```'s within the text which then get aligned next to each other and are not inside the text any more... i would like to avoid putting the li content inside a span itself if possible.

Comment: That sounds like another question.